# python file in dos and unix

Tags: python, linux

I have some python file in `windows`, and I transfer them to my `gentoo` by samba.

I check their mode is executable, and I use `./xxx.py` to run it, but get an error:

> : No such file or directory

I am troubled that it does not prompt what file is not here.

but when I use `python xxx.py`, it can run in the right way.

and then I check the CR character by use `set ff` in vim, and found it is `dos`, then I use `set ff=unix` to set it, now it can run by using `./xxx.py`

but I don't know why it can be use `python xxx.py` when `ff=dos`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOS files ends lines with CR+LF, Unix files just with LF. This means that when Unix reads your file to figure out what the executable name is, that executable's name ends in CR. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print("Blah!")
```

When I run that I get:

```
$ ./test.py 
bash: ./test.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What happens in your case is that the CR character (the ^M above) is not printed out but "executed" by your terminal, i.e., the cursor will return to the start of the line. Hence, everything before the ^M is overwritten:

```
$ ./test.py
```

: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

This is why you can't execute files with DOS file ending on Unix.

Any even remotely modern source control system will handle this for you, and change the file endings when you check out the source.

Comment: Not all source control systems will automatically mangle your line endings. For example, I know git requires you to turn on `autocrlf` if you want this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Windows line endings are CRLF, or `\r\n`.

Unix uses simply `\n`.

When the OS reads your shebang line, it sees `#!/usr/bin/python\r`. It can't run this command.

A simple way to see this behavior from a unix shell would be `$(echo -e 'python\r')` (which tries to run `python\r` as a command). This output will also be similar to `: command not found`.

Many advanced code editors under Windows support natively saving with unix line endings.